# Hanging indentation with linguex (Why does this work?)

Tags: indentation, linguex, cgloss4e

I wanted to create `linguex` examples where the free translation line has a hanging indent of 21.3 big points. I found that use of the `hanging` package, which is simple enough, does not work (second example in code). Reading the relevant section of the TeXbook (after three days) yielded a less simple solution which does work (first example in code). Why does use of the `hanging` package fail?

```
\tracingmacros=1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\ex .
\gll    Mundus vult decipi      \\
        world want deceive      \\
\glt    \dimen0=\the\textwidth
        \dimen1=\the\textwidth
        \dimen2=21.3bp
        \advance\dimen0 by -\the\labelwidth
        \advance\dimen1 by -\the\labelwidth
        \advance\dimen1 by -\dimen2
        \advance\dimen2 by \the\labelwidth
        \parshape=2 \the\labelwidth \dimen0 \dimen2 \dimen1
        \lipsum[2]



\ex .
\gll    Mundus vult decipi      \\
        world want deceive      \\
\glt    \hangpara{21.3bp}{2}\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Output of the above code is as follows:
[image]

Comment: The glossing macros (defined in `cgloss4e.sty`) are essentially lists, and so the indentation for them is set before the text of the paragraph is encountered.  The `\hangpara` macro uses the TeX macros `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` underlyingly, not the more general `\parshape` command. I don't know why the TeX `\parshape` command is able to override everything, but it clearly is.

Comment: @AlanMunn If both `\parshape` and `\hangindent` are non zero, then the former wins. In a list environment the declaration `\everypar{\parshape1\leftmargin\linewidth}` is executed (not the real truth, but a good approximation to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alan Munn says in his comment, `linguex` basically uses list environments; inside a list environment at every paragraph start an instruction `\parshape1` is executed, which wins over setting `\hangindent`. So any setting to `\hangindent` is ignored. You can use a `list` yourself: the setting is not difficult at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\ex .
\gll  Mundus vult decipi \\
      world want deceive \\
\glt  \begin{list}{}{%
        \leftmargin=21.3pt
        \itemindent=-\leftmargin}
      \item[]\lipsum*[2]
      \end{list}

\end{document}
```

You probably want to define your own environment for this:

```
\newcommand{myindentedpar}[1][21.3pt]
 {\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=#1 \itemindent=-\leftmargin}\item[]}
 {\end{list}}
```

so the above can be specified as

```
\glt  \begin{myindentedpar}
      \lipsum*[2]
      \end{myindentedpar}
```

A different amount of indentation can be specified in the optional argument

```
\begin{myindentedpar}[30pt]
\lipsum*[2]
\end{myindentedpar}
```

Here's the result with 21.3pt:

[image]