# Setting the left margin of a trivlist in an environment?

Tags: environments, indentation

I'm working on defining an environment that's further indented than the rest of the page.

This is my document so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}


\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}


\newenvironment{subq}[1]{\begin{trivlist}
\setlength\leftmargin{6cm}
\item[{\bfseries #1.}]}
{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

 \begin{question}{6}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{question}

\begin{subq}{a}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{subq}

\end{document}
```

I'd expect this to indent the subq by 6cm, but that doesn't happen.  It's totally aligned with everything else, except that the **a.** is a few extra points to the left.  I've tried replacing `leftmargin` with `parindent` and `leftmargini` to no effect.

I've also tried moving `leftmargin` before the `\begin{trivlist}`, like so:

```
\newenvironment{subq}[1]{\setlength\leftmargin{10cm} \begin{trivlist}
\item[{\bfseries #1.}]}
{\end{trivlist}}
```

and that gives me exactly the same output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `list` instead of `trivlist`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were nearly there, but the setting isn't trivial enough for `trivlist`, you want to use `list`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}


\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}


\newenvironment{subq}[1]{\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength\leftmargin{6cm}}%
\item[{\bfseries #1.}]}
{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\noindent X\dotfill X

 \begin{question}{6}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{question}

\begin{subq}{a}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{subq}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the low-level `\parshape` command. The answer to a [question I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145296/hanging-indentation-with-linguex-why-does-this-work) a few weeks ago explains its use in list environments. The code below specifies a 6cm left indent for all of `subq`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,lipsum}
\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{subq}[1]{\begin{trivlist}
        \dimen1=\the\textwidth
        \dimen2=6cm
        \advance\dimen1 by -\dimen2
        \parshape=1 \dimen2 \dimen1
\item[{\bfseries #1.}]}
{\end{trivlist}}
%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
 \begin{question}{6}
\lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\begin{subq}{a}
\lipsum[2]
\end{subq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: setting parshape inside a latex list is very brave:-)